# How To Create Dynamic Dashboards

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a form as Dashboards. I want to automatically refresh data without the data being read from the database and the user are shown.
What is the best late for this scenario? I did this using a timer, but the best for this scenario is late?

Comment: if you want the Data to be automatically refreshed without the data being read from the database..where are you expecting to read the data, Cache the data, ect..??

Comment: What kind of database? Some of them can cache data so you can read from memory.

Comment: What is a "form as Dashboards"? If you don't read the data from the database, what is the purpose of refreshing it? And most importantly... what are you actually asking?

Comment: @Andrew Barber  late is suggestion.

Comment: I would say in a time of 1 minute refresh operation can be performed

Comment: I do not use Memory Or Cache because they want real information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show data to user but you didn't want to crash your form you can Use background worker or use threads in advanced.